# Diagnosing SQL speeds

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2017

I just migrated a production DB onto some new hardware (in a sandbox setting) because they were suffering from poor IO performance.

Testing a simple select * from TABLE query on one of the large tables (123m rows, 24 columns) takes about 20 minutes.  I can see that the query maxes out a single core on the SQL server, but memory consumption and disk IO are non-existent.

In the resource monitor there are 0 waits, other than Network I/O which is at 700-800.
The query is being run from a local install of MSSQL Mgmt studio.

Data file I/0 is 0 in the activity monitor.
Wait time in the query is about double the active CPU time.

I am not sure if this is a problem that I need to solve, or that's just the way it works.
I was actually testing the speed of the query directly on the server vs. it being called by my users app - to diagnose if an ODBC driver might be holding things up, as reading from the database took 98% of the scripts time.

Ran a select * from query and was expecting it to complete much faster than it did.

EDIT:  Its SQL 2017

Comment: This is about SQL Server, not SQL. Please include the version of it

Comment: Why would you *need* to do a `SELECT *` on a table with 123,000,000 rows? Why do you need *all* the rows and *all* the columns from the table?

Comment: What's the question? `select * from query` isn't simple. What does `query` contain? Is it a table? A complex query or view that doesn't use indexes? If you want to see what the server does check the Execution Plan, both the estimated and actual. Both SSMS and Azure Data Studio can display a query's execution plan and even show a real time view that displays which operator is running at any time

Comment: `the query maxes out a single core on the SQL server` that means that 1) you're either not using the Developer/Enterprise edition or `query` explicitly disabled parallelization and 2) the `query` is doing something bad, forcing the database engine to perform a *lot* of crunching in memory, eg to hash rows, calculate missing indexes, sort etc. The execution plan will show you what's going on

Comment: Its SQL 2017 Standard Edition.  The query is a select * from a table.

Comment: But you haven't explained *why* you *need* that dataset, @Darkadmin . I honestly highly doubt you *need* a dataset with 123,000,000 rows and 24 columns returned to the user; what are they (the user) going to do with that data after they have it? Copy it into Excel? Excel doesn't support that many rows.

Comment: My users have written a program, they tried with a small part of the table and got errors, so took everything and it works.  I have just started down the path of investigating what it is they are doing, and I am asking the same questions.  However I am trying to figure out, if we have a general database performance issue or not.

Comment: Wow... a targeted query for the exact data the developers need didn't work, so they reverted to `SELECT *` on such a large table. Someone needs to reign them back in. Ask yourself, "Does selecting 123M rows actually test real-world server performance?" or  maybe "...does it test what SQL was designed for?" Larnu's points are spot on.

Comment: @TimJarosz you are both missing the point.  I know what my users are doing is not optimal.  That’s a topic for me to discuss with them.  What I am trying to ascertain is, is my SQL server doing something strange that I need to address at the server level, or is 20 minutes a reasonable time to execute such a silly query.  Is there an underlying problem?  The answer seems to be no, so now I can help my users do their jobs better.